# setting mime type for image files before they are encrypted with Shrine and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

My app encrypts and uploads certain files, and then makes them visible to admins. To achieve the latter functionality, [my encryption gem's documentation](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox#shrine) suggests a controller action that looks like this:

```
def show
 user = User.find(params[:id])
 lockbox = Lockbox.new(key: Lockbox.attribute_key(table: "id_docs", attribute: "image"))
 send_data lockbox.decrypt(user.id_docs.image.read), type: user.id_docs.image.mime_type, disposition: 'inline'
end
```

I want the file to stream, but the browser does not know how to interpret it, and downloads instead. This happens the files are encrypted before upload, and [Shrine](https://shrinerb.com/docs/getting-started) sets the mime type of these files to `application/octet-stream`.

My create action looks like this:

```
def create
 image = params.require(:id_doc).fetch(:image)
 respond_to do |format|
  if Shrine.mime_type(image) == 'image/jpeg'
   lockbox = Lockbox.new(key: Lockbox.attribute_key(table: "id_docs", attribute: "image"))
   encrypted_image = lockbox.encrypt_io(image)
   @id_doc = IdDoc.create(user_id: current_user.id, image: encrypted_image)
   @id_doc.save
   format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  else
   format.html { redirect_to current_path }
  end
 end
end
```

If I do *not* encrypt the files, the mime type is saved as `image/png` or `image/jpeg`, which is what I want.

**IdDoc.rb** has a virtual attribute called `:image` which maps to an `image_data` field in the database:

```
class IdDoc < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 validates_presence_of :image
 include IdDocUploader::Attachment(:image)
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "id_docs", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.bigint "user_id"
 t.text "image_data"
end
```

The data saved to `image_data` is saved in json format: `{\"id\":\"iddoc/1/image/2de32e77f306f0e95aed24623e930683.png\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"Screen Shot 2020-10-31 at 7.24.08 AM.png\",\"size\":47364,\"mime_type\":\"application/octet-stream\"}}`

How would I change the value of `mime_type` before the file creates? Is there any way to do this with Shrine, or should I go super hacky and parse that json directly?

Comment: Have you looked into what mine type is being used when returning the file to the browser? You might find that this is what is causing the download.

Comment: @jad how do i check this? i found this https://www.alexkras.com/copy-any-api-call-as-curl-request-with-chrome-developer-tools/ but i'm confused because i don't make API calls when performing this action

Comment: `type: user.id_docs.image.mime_type` ... have you inspected what the types are?

Comment: i'm confused by what you mean. the file downloads as "id_doc" and can be viewed only after i manually add a .jpg or .png (which are the two formats that my validations allow).

Comment: @jad just realized the op might not be clear, so i've added some more info

Comment: "Application/octet-stream" is a binary format. If you're expecting images, you need to return an image mime-type that matches the data ... "image/jpeg" for instance

Comment: Yes you are right! I just found that out yesterday. The issue is: 1) Lockbox encrypts files before they are saved, and 2) Shrine, the gem I use for uploading files to S3, is detecting the mime type of that binary file instead of the mime type of the image before it's saved.

Comment: you could try using something like: https://flylib.com/books/en/2.44.1/converting_one_image_format_to_another.html and forcing the file format to be jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply said: I think you're not quite doing this in the way Shrine intends and there's multiple ways to remedy this. I'll rank them from (in my opinion, based on complexity/appropriateness) best to worst:

- Encryption could/should be treated as a part of Shrine's processing/derivatives concept. So you'd want to perform the processing there and set the metadata accordingly. The Shrine author himself has outlined solutions to process the original file in a thread here: https://discourse.shrinerb.com/t/keep-original-file-after-processing/50.
- You can override metadata manually: https://shrinerb.com/docs/metadata#controlling-extraction. This would probably mean not using attribute based assignment but instead calling the attacher directly (see below).
- You can define your own MIME type determining logic as set out here: https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/determine_mime_type.
- You're using `Shrine.mime_type` already. Use the value you get from this and store it in a separate database column `mime_type` on your `id_docs` model and then use it when you're reading from the database. Note that this probably implicitly means that the value in this column and the value you get from the file's metadata's mime type are out of sync.

---

Using the attacher directly:

```rb
mime_type = Shrine.mime_type(image)

# ...

@id_doc = IdDoc.create(user_id: current_user.id) do |id_doc|
  id_doc.image_attacher.model_assign(encrypted_image, metadata: { mime_type: mime_type })
end
```